# snow leopard (osx): sudo preserving environment

Tags: bash, mac-osx, sudo, osx-snow-leopard, alias

Greetings,

I would like to preserve my aliases after sudoing on OSX:

```
sudo -s
. .profile
```

Is it possible to achieve this on a SINGLE command line?  - i.e. something like:

```
sudo -s ; . .profile
```

tks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bash problem.  I use zsh and my aliases are kept after doing a sudo -s.

Comment: Do `sudo -E` or `sudo -i` do anything useful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your aliases from `.profile` to `.bashrc`.  (`bash` *is* the default Mac OS X shell now, right?)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to modify your sudoers file:

```
# Defaults specification
Defaults    env_keep += "VISUAL EDITOR"
```

You can include (or omit) anything you want, placing each of them on an individual line if you'd like.

Here's the default Leopard sudoers env_keep list:

```
# Defaults specification
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
```